# Airflow 1.9 - Tasks stuck in queue

Tags: postgresql, centos, rabbitmq, celery, airflow

Latest Apache-Airflow install from PyPy (1.9.0)

**Set up includes:**

1. Apache-Airflow
2. Apache-Airflow[celery]
3. RabbitMQ 3.7.5
4. Celery 4.1.1
5. Postgres

I have the installation across 3 hosts.

**Host #1**

- Airflow Webserver
- Airflow Scheduler
- RabbitMQ Server
- Postgres Server

**Host #2**

- Airflow Worker

**Host #3**

- Airflow Worker

I have a simple DAG that executes a BashOperator Task that runs every 1 minute. I can see the scheduler "queue" the job however, it nevers gets added to a Celery/RabbitMQ queue and gets picked up by the workers. I have a custom RabbitMQ user, authentication seems fine. Flower, however, doesn't show any of the queues populating with data. It does see the two worker machines listening on their respective queues.

**Things I've checked:**

- Airflow Pool configuration
- Airflow environment variables
- Upgrade/Downgrade Celery and RabbitMQ
- Postgres permissions
- RabbitMQ Permissions
- DEBUG level airflow logs

I read the documentation section about jobs not running. My "start_date" variable is a static date that exists before the current date.

OS: Centos 7

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out but I'm not sure why this is the answer.

Changing the "broker_url" variable to use "pyamqp" instead of "amqp" was the fix.